# huxtable in R defaults to scientific notation even with options(scipen=999)

Tags: r

I was trying to generate decent tables and tried so many packages in the past week my head is swimming. Started on package:huxtable this morning and got stuck trying to get rid of scientific notation:

```
x <- mtcars[1:5,1:2]
x$mpg <- x$mpg*10000000 # get some large numbers
library(huxtable)
x1 <- as_hux(x)
x1
  # 2.1e+08    6        
  # 2.1e+08    6        
  # 2.28e+08   4        
  # 2.14e+08   6        
  # 1.87e+08   8
```

I set global options(scipen=999, digits = 9) some time ago and haven't had any problems till package:huxtable. Eventually I found/stumbled on a solution with:

```
x1 <- format(as_hux(x, scientific=FALSE))
```

I had scipen already set, so I ended up going back and forth trying to fix something that was not broken. My (quasi-noob) question: Am I right in concluding that for some reason this package is overriding a global  setting? Is there a way to prevent that from happening or set up some kind of warning when an override has occurred? Possible to set this format globally? I don't expect to use scientific notation any time soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "`print()`" method (by typing `x1` variable name), it's up to the package how it is going to output the values. It uses it's own display method for that. It happens that whoever wrote this package do not look at the global options set by options() function. It does not overwrite any options but simply ignores them.
If however you extract a column out of `x1` structure, R will print the values in the desirable format:

```
> print(x1$mpg)
[1] 210000000 210000000 228000000 214000000 187000000
```

A side note: This is not the only package that does this.

By the way, the solution you found ( `format()` function )  in reality converts the data back into regular data frame and therefore displays the values using scipen=999 option you set.

Comment: TY. I realized format() was converting a huxtable back to data.frame after you pointed it out. I revisited number_format() in the vignette which I skipped over very early in the process  as "not relevant" because my data had no decimals and anything thus marked is as if I never saw it. I'm guessing the person who wrote this package has an advanced degree in math or the like - I don't know many, or any, ordinary mortals who want and can read html tables in scientific notation and can make sense of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `number_format()` option to change how huxtable displays numbers:

```
number_format(x1) <- 2 # decimal places
x1
  210000000.00      6.00  
  210000000.00      6.00  
  228000000.00      4.00  
  214000000.00      6.00  
  187000000.00      8.00  
Column names: mpg, cyl

number_format(x1) <- '%2.2f' # sprintf notation
x1
  210000000.00      6.00  
  210000000.00      6.00  
  228000000.00      4.00  
  214000000.00      6.00  
  187000000.00      8.00  

Column names: mpg, cyl

# arbitrary function, wrapped in a list:
number_format(x1) <- list(function (x) prettyNum(sprintf(x, "%2.2f"), ",")) 
x1
  210,000,000.00      6.00  
  210,000,000.00      6.00  
  228,000,000.00      4.00  
  214,000,000.00      6.00  
  187,000,000.00      8.00
```

Comment: If you wanted the numbers to not be formatted at all you can use
` ``number_format(x1) <- NA```