# Year in a package::huxtable table footnote is defaulting to scientific notion

Tags: r

I am trying to add a footnote containing a 4 digit year to a table using package::huxtable. The year gets outputted in scientific notation. I encountered the same problem in reference to numbers in the body of the table and to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080713/huxtable-in-r-defaults-to-scientific-notation-even-with-optionsscipen-999),  @katia explained what was going on. But now I'm stuck trying to solve the same problem but in a footnote to the table:

```
options(scipen = 100, digits = 10)
library(huxtable)
t <- huxtable(mtcars[1:5, 1:2])
number_format(t) <- 1
add_footnote(t, "No cars in 1776")
```

The footnote prints as:

```
# No cars in 1.78e+03
```

I'm at a loss to understand what's going on - the number_format() sets decimal places to 1 for the whole table. Or is supposed to. Dropping it reverts the whole table to scientific notation. Putting 1776 in quotes results in error:

```
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "add_footnote(t, "No cars in "1776"
```

Any pointers / help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`footnote` in a `huxtable` carries its own properties - you can pass additional arguments, which is then passed on to `set_cell_properties

> Arguments
>   ... Other properties, passed to set_cell_properties for the footnote cell.

Specifying `number_format` as an additional argument to `add_footnote` should work

```
add_footnote(t, "No cars in 1776", number_format = 0)

  # 21.0           6.0           
  # 21.0           6.0           
  # 22.8           4.0           
  # 21.4           6.0           
  # 18.7           8.0           
# ───────────────────────────────
  # No cars in 1776              

# Column names: mpg, cyl
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked.  I tried wrapping in format() but didn't think to pass number_format().